# RealmObject update sameFields

Tags: android, realm

Good Day.
I use Realm java.
I have a model. How I can  update only one models field, without changing the rest.

```
public class StatsticsLvl extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
String id;
String gameId;

Boolean cap;// i need update only this field
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the object and update it should work?

```
realm.beginTransaction();
StatsticsLvl obj = realm.where(StatsticsLvl.class).equalTo("id", myId).findFirst();
obj.setcap(true);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

See the documentation on how to write to Realm here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#writes